# How to integrate kafka connect with java so that it can read csv file and forward the data to the consumer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to use kafka connect with java such that the source connector will the pick the csv file, create a topic and send the message to the consumer.
Note:- Have to use kafka connect.

Answer (score 0):

Connect is not meant to be used as an embedded client; Apache Camel can be used instead, and is very similar

- https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/dataformats/csv-dataformat.html
- https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/kafka-component.html